# Using the return values of dynamic classes

Tags: python, class, oop, python-2.7, dynamic

I have a type of file that I work with where each line represents a different "model" and each model has certain attributes. From file to file those attributes can change so I wrote dynamic class to read these files. Which is -

```
class readmags:
    def __init__(self, fname):
        self.data = open(fname, 'r')
        # Read header to find the columns in the file
        while True:
            line = self.data.readline()
            line = line.lstrip()
            if line[0] == '#':
                header = line.replace('#', '')
                header =  header.split()
                break
        self.header = header

    def next(self):
        line = self.data.readline()
        if line == "":
            self.data.close()
            raise StopIteration()

        # Read in and assign the  attributes of the models
        cols = line.split()
        for i, name in enumerate(self.header):
            self.__dict__[name] = float(cols[i])
        return self.__dict__

    def __iter__(self):
        return self
```

And this seems to do exactly what I want, however, the behavior of the object that it returns confuses me. I like to select models based on attributes so if I try,

```
catalog = readmags(<test_file>)
young = []
for model in catalog:
    if model['phase'] != 6.0:
       young.append(model)
```

And, again, this works as I'd expect. The problem comes in when I try to select attributes in the 'young' list, then it just returns the same values for however many entries are in the list. For example,

```
for blah in young:
    print blah['age']
```

Just returns the same value. I'm still new to object oriented programming and making classes so I may just be misunderstanding what's being returned to me from readmags. I'd really appreciate it if anyone could explain to me what's going on and how to do what I'd like to do.

Editing to add a small data set to test on -

```
 # age log(Z) mass logl logt logg phase log(weight)
 5.5000  -2.4089   0.0800  -3.6100   3.3644   5.3500   0.0000  -0.5591
 5.5000  -2.4089   0.0900  -3.2700   3.4219   5.2920   0.0000  -0.3456
 5.5000  -2.4089   0.1000  -3.0700   3.4492   5.2510   0.0000  -0.4535
 5.5000  -2.4089   0.1100  -2.9300   3.4655   5.2180   0.0000  -0.3965
 5.5000  -2.4089   0.1300  -2.7300   3.4852   5.1690   0.0000  -0.4183
 5.5000  -2.4089   0.1500  -2.4002   3.5584   5.1938   0.0000  -0.3674
```

As well as a test program -

```
models = readmags(<test_file>)
young = []
for model in models:
    if model['age'] == 5.5:
        print model['mass']
        young.append(model)

for star in young:
    print star['mass']
```

Shouldn't both print statements being printing out the same thing? They're not and I don't understand why.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example of data for testing? Why are you modifying the instance's `__dict__`, instead of returning a new structure?

Comment: I modify `__dict__` so that I can dynamically create the class attributes.

Answer (score -9, accepted):

When you iterate over the `catalog`, each time you:

```
return self.__dict__
```

which is added to your `young` list:

```
young.append(model)
```

This means that `young` contains *multiple references to the same dictionary*, which is modified on each iteration of the loop (each time `catalog.next` is called). Therefore when you subsequently iterate over `young`, you see the same value over and over again.

You could return a copy of the dictionary instead:

```
return self.__dict__.copy()
```

or create and return a new dictionary, rather than modifying the instance's `__dict__`.

Comment: Thank you very much. That fixed the issue and I understand what the problem was now.